# How to register callback of App Invite Dialogue

Tags: android, facebook

This is my code working fine.I am am getting invitaton.
All of the code working .

Q)How to show log messages of callback.

Q) Why I can not get log messages in logcat.

```
if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                .setApplinkUrl(AppURl)
                .build();

        AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(getActivity());
        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                        Log.d("Invitation", "Invitation Sent Successfully");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invitation Sent Succseesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("Invitation", "Invitation Cancel Successfully");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                        Log.d("Invitation", "Error Occured");
                    }
                });

        appInviteDialog.show(content);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    sCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);


}
```

**Note :  I also register callback in OnActivitResutl.**

*Please Suggest Something If Question is Wrong. I am new on Stackoverflow.*

**Edit**

When i use same code with Activity it works but when I use Fragment It does not work.
Why any explanation or code error ?

Comment: Please suggest me what can I do ?

Comment: did you solve problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass "FragmentName.this" instead of "getActivity" if you registering it from the fragment.

```
AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(this);
```